# Rails 4 order by virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Product` model which has `name` and `description` columns in the database.

I also have a `Product.search_results_for(query)`, where `query` is a string like `"Green Apple"`.

I need to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of the results ordered by which is the best hit. Currently, I'm setting a `search_result_value` to each product. `search_result_value` IS NOT a column in the database, and I don't want it to be.

So in essence, I have an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Products` that I need to order by `search_result_value` without changing it to an array, which is an instance variable that isn't stored in the database. How can I do this?

Something like this:

```
Product.order(:search_result_value)
```

Comment: How complicated is the `search_result_value` computation? You can ORDER BY any expression that you can expression in SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not put the value in a column or express the logic in `search_result_value` in pure SQL, then you’ll have to load all Products into memory and then sort them in Ruby using [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
Product.all.to_a.sort_by(&:search_result_value)
```

Comment: Thanks, but are there any ways of doing this without converting it to an array? As in, sort the ActiveRecord::Relation by the respective object's instance variables?

Comment: Here, the ``to_a`` call is not necessary. Now Active Record relations are lazy loaded, so calling ``sort_by`` on an active record relation will implicitely convert it to an array and then call ``sort_by`` on it.

Comment: @Mavvie, the ActiveRecord::Relation is just a query, not a result set. So, you can write SQL to calculate the field for you, or you need pull the records into an array and sort them with Ruby.

Comment: @Intrepidd, I know it’s not needed, but I think it’s more clear, especially since `all` used to be an Array but is now a Relation starting in Rails 4. And no @Mavvie, there is not—the database has no idea your Ruby exists and the instance variable doesn’t exist till you’ve loaded the objects into Ruby-land.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for forgetting about this comment. I never ended up implementing it (The fact I wanted to do an SQL order() by a ruby virtual attribute just makes no sense lol. I'm now using [Searchkick](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick), which has come a long way since I started using it last year.