# Sort by a model method in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model, I have this method which takes the last_name and first_name columns for an object and concatenates them into a string.

```
def name
  last_name + " " + first_name
end
```

I want to define a scope that can sort my objects by that method. How would one go about doing that, using my method? I don't want to define some scope that first sorts by last_name, and then by first_name in the scope (if that's even possible). My understanding that you can only scope on actual columns in the rails framework? Is that incorrect?

Here's what I wrote, but obviously neither works, as there is no `name` field in my `AdminUser` table. Not sure why the second one doesn't work, but I'm guessing that the `:name_field` wouldn't work, as it's not actually in the model/database as a column.

```
scope :sorted, lambda { order("name ASC")}
scope :sorted, lambda { :name_field => name, order("name_field ASC")}
```

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295778/rails-4-order-by-virtual-attribute

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do this directly from Ruby/Rails to SQL. You could achieve what you want in two ways

You can load all the users into memory and sort them in Ruby

```
User.all.to_a.sort_by(&:name)
```

Or you can define an order in SQL as such

```
ORDER BY CONCAT(users.last_name, ' ', users.first_name) ASC;
```

In Rails, you'd have to do the following

```
scope :sorted, -> { 
  order("CONCAT(users.last_name, ' ', users.first_name) ASC") 
}
```

Do note that this may not be portable between DBs.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks :)